# ERROR 500 on VB NET JQUERY AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I trying list in select option with jquery ajax, but I need help!

this is error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:20440/admin/cadastro.aspx/GetMarcas
```

my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({


type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            url: "cadastro.aspx/GetMarcas",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {


$('#marca').empty();
                $('#marca').append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");
                $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {
                    $("#marca").append($("<option></option>").val(value.Codigo).html(value.Descricao));
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.aspx">DASHBOARD <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="cadastro.aspx">CADASTRO <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="listagem.aspx">ITEMS CADASTRADOS <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">



        <form action="/" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Marca</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="marca" id="marca" runat="server">
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Modelo</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="modelo" id="modelo" runat="server">
                    <option value="value">text</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Cor</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="cor" id="cor" runat="server">
                    <option value="value">text</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Ano</label>
                <input type="text" name="ano" id="ano" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Placa</label>
                <input type="text" name="placa" id="placa" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Services
Partial Class admin_cadastro
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then marca() End
End Sub

Public Class Marca
    Public Property Codigo() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Codigo
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Codigo = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Codigo As Integer
    Public Property Descricao() As String
        Get
            Return m_Descricao
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Descricao = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Descricao As String
End Class

<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function GetMarcas() As List(Of Marca)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim objMarca As New List(Of Marca)()

    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conStr").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("exec sp_ListaMarcas", con)
            con.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    objMarca.Add(New Marca() With {
                        .Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)("Codigo")),
                        .Descricao = dt.Rows(i)("Descricao").ToString()
                    })
                Next
            End If
            Return objMarca
        End Using
    End Using
End Function





End Class
```

I not using method postback, I need help regarding this error, so that the option list data from the database.

Comment: Do you have more information on the exception that occurs on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

This article should help a lot for jQuery/Webforms integration:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95525/ASP-NET-and-jQuery-to-the-Max

First thing you should check is if you reach the server side by adding a breakpoint in your `GetMarcas` method. If you reach it, you will be able to debug your way in the method and have more information on the error.

Looking at your code, it might be as simple as the string parameter you send to initialize the command. My guess is that you want to call a stored procedure called `sp_ListaMarcas`. If so, you don't need the `exec` part. You should do it like this:

```
Using cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_ListaMarcas", con)
```